# 'requires' clause with fold expressions never satisfied

Tags: c++, constraints, c++20, requires-clause

I'm struggling a lot to understand how concepts and contraints works. Until now I always managed to avoid them with type traits and `static_assert` or `std::enable_if` (or even SFINAE) but I want to reconcile with [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) (well, for that part at least, since I have the same understanding struggles for almost anything that was added with [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)).

---

I have a function with a variadic template parameter for which I want to accept only integral values that are above a threshold, let's say `2`.

For that purpose I defined an `integral` concept, and then I add a `requires` clause to add the threshold constraint, which gives me this:

```
template <typename T>
concept integral = std::is_integral<T>::value;

template <integral ... Ts>
void f(Ts ... ts) requires (... && (ts > 2))
{
   //blablabla
}
```

This compiles fine. But when I try to call `f()` with argumentsn for example `f(8, 6);`, I always get a compile-time error (GCC): `error: 'ts#0' is not a constant expression`

The full error trace (GCC):

> ```
> <source>: In substitution of 'template<class ... Ts>  requires (... && integral<Ts>) void f(Ts >...) requires (... && ts > 2) [with Ts = {int, int}]':
> <source>:15:6:   required from here
> <source>:8:6:   required by the constraints of 'template<class ... Ts>  requires (... && integral<Ts>) void f(Ts ...) requires (... && ts > 2)'
> <source>:8:43: error: 'ts#0' is not a constant expression
>    8 | void f(Ts ... ts) requires (... && (ts > 2))
>      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
> <source>: In function 'int main()':
> <source>:15:6: error: no matching function for call to 'f(int, int)'
>   15 |     f(8, 6);
>      |     ~^~~~~~
> <source>:8:6: note: candidate: 'template<class ... Ts>  requires (... && integral<Ts>) void f(Ts >...) requires (... && f::ts > 2)'
>    8 | void f(Ts ... ts) requires (... && (ts > 2))
>      |      ^
> <source>:8:6: note:   substitution of deduced template arguments resulted in errors seen above
> ```

What I don't understand is why are the arguments required to be constant expressions, and why is `8` not considered as such ?

Comment: Constraints can’t use the values of (function) parameters, which are never constant expressions: what would happen for a call with a runtime value that “unexpectedly” failed to satisfy the constraint?

Comment: this wouldnt work with static_assert or `std::enable_if` as well. If you make `ts` a template argument, it will work in both worlds. Very roughly speaking, concepts doesnt make you do new things, but it lets you write them down in a much nicer way

Comment: in other words, try to do the same without concept, by appliying good ol' SFINAE. If you got that then the transition to using a concept will be simpler

Comment: Oh right, I mixed compile-time mechanisms with runtime things... I feel dumb :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values of function parameters cannot be used in function constraints. A much simpler way to reproduce your problem is this:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

// note: there already is a concept for integral types
//       also, we can use an abbreviated function template
void f(std::integral auto x) requires (x > 2)
{
    // ...
}

void foo() {
    f(0);
}
```

This produces the error:

```
<source>:3:40: error: substitution into constraint expression
                      resulted in a non-constant expression
void f(std::integral auto x) requires (x > 2)
                                       ^~~~~
<source>:9:5: note: while checking constraint satisfaction
              for template 'f<int>' required here
    f(0);
    ^
```

The value of `x` is not known at compile time, and function constraints can only verify compile-time properties. Even though we are calling `f` with `x = 0`, `f` needs to work with *all* possible arguments, not just `0`.

If you want a type which can only hold values greater than two, you can do that:

```cpp
template <std::integral T>
class greater_two_integer {
private:
    T v;
public:
    greater_two_integer(T x) : v{x} {
        assert(x > 2);
    }

    operator T() const noexcept {

// OPTIONAL: aid compiler optimizations
#if __has_cpp_attribute(assume)
        [[assume(v > 2)]];
#elif defined(__clang__)
        __builtin_assume(v > 2);
#elif __cpp_lib_unreachable == 202202L
        // from <utility>
        if (v <= 2) std::unreachable();
#endif

        return v;
    }
};
```

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(greater_two_integer<T> x) { /* ... */ }

void g(greater_two_integer<int> x) { /* ... */ }

int main() {
    f(greater_two_integer{10}); // OK
    g(10); // OK

    f(greater_two_integer{0}); // runtime check fails
    g(0); // runtime check fails
}
```

*See [live example](https://godbolt.org/z/zMxEEE4ze)*

#### Notes on `[[assume(v > 2)]]`

We use [`[[assume]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/assume) (since C++23) to enable compiler optimizations based on the fact that `greater_two_integer` always contains a value which is `> 2`.
The attribute is applied to an empty statement in the conversion operator, so when we extract the value from the object, it is undefined behavior if `v <= 2`.

This is safe, because the constructor contains `assert(v > 2)`, meaning:

- we always write a value `v > 2` first, and
- we can assume that we will later read a value `v > 2`

*Technically*, you can break this class invariant by `std::memcpy`ing into the class, or by writing its value through `reinterpret_cast<int*>`.
However, with both of these methods you're obviously shooting yourself in the foot, they don't happen by accident.